# Deconvolution of two delta functions (solving $y(t) = A x(t-a) + B x(t-b)$)

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, convolution, deconvolution

I would like to calculate $x(t)$, when only $y(t)$ with

$y(t) = A x(t-a) + B x(t-b)$

is known.

Since this is a linear shift invariant operation (convolution), the inverse relation must be of the form

$x(t) = (y * g)(t)  =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty y(t-\tau) g(\tau) \mathrm d \tau$

The question is: what is $g(\tau)$? I am sure this problem has been solved before, but I cannot find any suitable references.

Also I would be interested in solutions to the equation with three or more terms (the shifts can be equidistant though).

I know that there may be (some) situations where this equation has no solution, but I think not in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the theorem that convolution in the time domain is the multiplication of the Fourier transforms.  So $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)G(\omega)$ where the capital letters represent the Fourier Transforms of the lower case letters.

We can also use the shift theorem.  What is $Y(\omega)$?  $Y(\omega)=Ae^{-i\omega a}X(\omega) + Be^{-i\omega b}X(\omega)$

Factoring out the $X(\omega)$ we can solve for $G(\omega)$  If you find a inverse transform of $G$ then you have found $g$.

By the way, are you sure there's an easily expression for $g$?  Based on what you're taking the inverse transform of, I'm not sure there is.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have an (as explicit as possible) expression for $g$.

Comment: @AndreasH.  In general, this cannot be done.  Suppose that $x$ is a triangle waveform, and that $a$ and $b$ shift $x$ by 1/2.  Let $A=B=1$.  Then $y=0$.  So was $x$ a triangle waveform shifted by 1/2?  Or was $x=0$, which would yield the same result?  One can never know.